# Convert less "for loop" to scss "for loop"

Tags: function, for-loop, sass, less, converters

Could anybody help me to understand what does it mean this bunch of code in less format and what would be in scss format. Thanks for any help.

```
.for(@i, @n) {.-each(@i)}
.for(@n)     when (isnumber(@n)) {.for(1, @n)}
.for(@i, @n) when not (@i = @n)  {
    .for((@i + (@n - @i) / abs(@n - @i)), @n);
}
```

Comment: This is a mixin (named `.for`) that calls another mixin (`.each`) with parameters changing from `@i` to `@n`. *what would be in scss format* - This code won't make any sense in SCSS - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to convert a less format to SCSS format. I don't have enough knowledge about less so this part of code was not clear to me. Thank you for your good and quick answer. I was confused about for loop  and .for and each loop and .-each.